# OptaPlanner dependencies via Gradle within IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jar, optaplanner

I read through the OptaPlanner [documentation](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.20.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#useWithMavenGradleEtc) and within, it describes how the dependencies can be mapped with Maven, Gradle, etc.  That said, it only references the Maven POM configuration.  Does anyone happen to know the dependency mapping for Gradle?  I'm a bit green with automated dependency management and would love *NOT* to have to download and manually map the Jar file(s).  I've grown to enjoy Gradle, except when I can't find a Gradle option for dependencies.  =(

Your help would be appreciated.

Best Regards!

Comment: Good point that the docs should mention Gradle too though.

Comment: PR's added to add these grdle docs for 7.21.0. see https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/pull/504 and  https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-website/pull/140

Answer (score 2):

Follow [the documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUshR.png), open the [Maven repository page for the dependency you need](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.optaplanner/optaplanner-core/7.20.0.Final/bundle).

On the right you will see the format for Gradle:

```
implementation 'org.optaplanner:optaplanner-core:7.20.0.Final'
```

In IntelliJ IDEA open `build.gradle` file and inside the `dependencies` section of this file [paste this very line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hF4Ne.png). Refresh Gradle projects as suggested by the IDE notification to get the dependency downloaded and added to the project.